# Is there a css parser within js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a css parser within js?

like F("#a") will return me the element with id a.

F(".asd") will return me the elements belonging to class asd

F("p#g") will return me the p element with id g.

F("p") will return me all the p elements

etc etc

i mean i know we can probably hand-code all the rules ourselves but there got to be a better way around that right?

Comment: I think you are looking for a JS framework like jQuery - http://www.jquery.com

Comment: im looking at HOW to do it without jQuery

Comment: If those are all the rules you need, then you can write it yourself

Comment: What you are asking is a CSS selector parser, not a CSS parser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector) and/or [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), but it doesn't have the best browser support, thanks to IE.

For better browser support, use [SizzleJS](http://sizzlejs.com/), the selector engine in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It will use `querySelectorAll()` where supported.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: im looking at HOW to do it without jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that, buddy.

Comment: im looking at HOW to do it without jQuery